# Waiting for *ngFor to build the page to perform DOM Manipulation

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, angular6

Community,

i am having some problems with my Angular 6 - App which i'm unfortunately not able to solve after hours of thinking & searching on google.

I've got a component that is displaying Meetings, Projects and Tasks in a Form. Those forms require a lot of data from different collections to select from (if the user wants to change something). All of those are being loaded in my ngOnInit:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.meetServ.getCompanyMeetings(false)
      .subscribe(data => this.meetings = data as meeting[]);
    this.deptServ.getCompanyDepartments()
      .subscribe(data => this.depts = data as department[]);
    this.CusServ.getCompanyCustomers()
      .subscribe(data => this.customers = data as customer[]);
    this.UserServ.getCompanyUsers()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.users = data as user[];
      })
  }
```

When I'm done loading all the data, I want to set all of the dropdown menus to the right values. So I put a setDropdowns method in the subscription of the last http-request I am doing (also tried out of subscription).
The extend() Method is called by onclick event as soon as the User selects a Meeting:

```
extend(meetingID) {
    document.getElementById("overlay").remove()
    this.meetServ.getMeetingbyID(meetingID)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.singleMeeting = data as meeting
        this.init(); //gets all the projects by ID of selected Meeting
        this.setMeetingAccessLevel();
        this.setMeetingComments();
        this.setDropdowns(); // tried like this
      })
      this.setDropdowns(); // and like this
  }
```

and my setDropdowns() Method looks like this:

```
  setDropdowns() {
    var projectDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div.projectContent");
    console.log(this.projects.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < this.projects.length; i++) {
      // Access Level
      var opts = projectDivs[i].querySelector("#access").querySelectorAll("option");
      (<HTMLOptionElement>opts[this.projects[i].accessLevel]).selected = true;
      // Department
      opts = projectDivs[i].querySelector("select#dept").querySelectorAll("option");
      for (var j = 0; j < this.depts.length; j++) {
        if (this.depts[j]._id == this.projects[i].department) {
          opts[j + 1].selected = true
        }
      }
      //Customer
      opts = projectDivs[i].querySelector("select#proCustomer").querySelectorAll("option")
      for (var k = 0; k < this.customers.length; k++) {
        if (this.customers[k]._id == this.projects[i].customer) {
          opts[k + 1].selected = true
        }
      }
      //Official
      var asd = (<HTMLSelectElement>projectDivs[i].querySelector("select#proinCharge")).querySelectorAll("option")
      for (var l = 0; l < this.users.length; l++) {
        /* if (this.users[l]._id == this.projects[i].inCharge) {
          asd[l].selected = true
        } */
      }
    }
  }
```

But when I look at the console, this.projects.length is either 0 or 2 (which is the actual number of projects in that meeting). The thing is, when I get it to log 2, the projectDivs[i].querySelector("#access") part errors "Cannot read property 'querySelector' of undefined", which actually makes no sense, since projectDivs are generated like this:

```
<div class="projectContent" id="projectContent" *ngFor="let project of projects">
```

and console.log(this.projects.length) returns 2 earlier.

So projects are loaded but the HTML seems to not be loaded properly at that point.
Now for sure i googled this a lot and tried out stuff like jQuery document.ready and checked if document.readyState == complete, but it seems to only apply to the static document and not to the *ngFor generated elements.

So obviously my question in the end is: Is there any way to wait for all *ngFor generated elements or is there just a much easier way of doing this which is wasn't able to spot?

Thanks in advance for all the upcoming answers.

Greetings

Comment: If these are forms, why aren't you letting angular solve the DOM manipulation? Are these [template-driven forms or reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms)? If you set your forms correctly, you might not need the `setDropdowns()` function

Comment: I actually didn't know i could do interrogations in for example [selected]... thank you so much, i've been hanging on this problem for quite a while.

Comment: Yeah. Do the research first. I am 99.99% sure that you don't need `JQuery` at all. That's the whole point of `Angular`... you don't actually need to do anything with the DOM yourself.